# How can I add icons to Calendar component in android? I want to show free days using userfriendy graphics

Tags: java, android

Nowadays I get JSON data {day1, day2, day3...}. How can I add images/icons to this.. ?

```
    CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(90, 40, 80, 40);
    calendarView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's not possible with this specific component since there's no public method to add image. You can check the [`CalendarView documentantion`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView).

I'd recommend to you two ways :
Either you create your own `GridLayout` or your `CalendarCustomView` so you specify your layout and in each cell (that would be the day) you add a space for an `ImageView` and use it.

Or use a library that does what you want.

Just chose the one that fits better with your needs.

An example of library could be :
[`Nevalla CalendarView`](https://github.com/nevalla/CalendarView)
[`Applandeo Material Calendar View`](https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View)
Etc...